# jQuery wizard plugin validate on name

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-validate, cakephp-2.1

I am using [jQuery Wizard](http://www.wbotelhos.com/stepy/) plugin and validating using the jQuery Validate plugin - developing in CakePHP 2.1

The jQuery wizard/validation.

It is supposed to be set up like this:

```
$(function(){
$("#JobAdCreateForm").formwizard({ 
    historyEnabled : true,
    validationEnabled: true,
    focusFirstInput : true,
    outDuration : 100,  
    validationOptions : {
        rules: {
            JobAdJobTitle: "required",
            JobAdCategoryId: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            JobAdJobTitle: "Please enter a job title.",
            JobAdCategoryId: "Please select a category.",
        }
    }
});  
});
```

In CakePHP the name attribute of the field looks like this: 
`data[JobAd][job_title]` now that gives an error when I change the name attribute above to `data[JobAd][job_title]`. It would have worked perfect if the `jquery.validate` used the `id` attribute instead of the `name` atribute.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you quote the name attribute?

```
rules: {
    "data[JobAd][job_title]": "required"
    // etc
}
```

Comment: thats it!! Thanks a million. I actually tried with sigle quotes.